# how to run docker commands in my windows command prompt?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-machine, boot2docker

I am running docker commands in the docker quick start terminal. I need to run those commands in my windows terminal. When I check the version of docker, It shows correctly but when I run `docker ps` or other docker commands. It shows like :

```
C:\Users\rajasekar.sambandam>docker ps
error during connect: Get http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.29/containers
/json: open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate that the docker daemon is not running.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, docker runs in the background in an linux VM. The quick start terminal delegates all the calls to the VM, and thats why the docker commands work.

When running from a normal terminal, run the command:

```
eval $(docker-machine env default)
```

This command will connect the current terminal to the backgound machine.

Comment: Thanks @yamenk. After setting environment variables, It works. But I am not able to run "docker-compose up"  in windows cmd.